# Can Spark executors be spawned in already running java process (Ignite JVM)

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I am working on a project where I need to **share** execution state across different spark application.

I decided to go with apache-ignite as a shared memory storage between different spark application.

I was thinking of going with **embedded ignite mode with static allocation** in spark where
ignite nodes will start in Spark executor process. So that, tasks will be executed in the same process where Data is present. But, this mode is **deprecated**.

I could go with standalone Ignite deployment but there would be inter-process communication to get and save the state which I want to avoid.

**Is there any way to tell the Spark to create its executors in already present process (in this case, Ignite nodesprocesses) ?**

Can **ExternalClusterManager** be implemented to achieve this ?

Does Ignite is planning to introduce such mode in future ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes, your general direction is reasonable. Ignite's deprecated embedded deployment is, so to say, embedded "backwards" - when you embed Ignite into Spark it works poorly, but if we embedded Spark into Ignite, it would work better.

Yes, I assume it would be possible to implement. It probably could even be implemented outside of Ignite.

I don't think there are any open issues for that in Ignite backlog, but you can share you suggestions on [Ignite dev mailing list](https://ignite.apache.org/community/resources.html).

**And now the main part.** All you're going to achieve with your suggestion is replacing inter-process communication with intra-process. Usually, communication on the same host isn't that expensive. You might see some performance gain from this but I'd only went into implementing this if there were a solid evidence that this is going to solve a real problem.